# C++11 Tagged Tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

C++11 tuples are nice, but they have two huge disadvantages to me, accessing members by index is

1. unreadable
2. difficult to maintain (if I add an element in the middle of the tuple, I'm screwed)

In essence what I want to achieve is this

```
tagged_tuple <name, std::string, age, int, email, std::string> get_record (); {/*...*/}
// And then soomewhere else

std::cout << "Age: " << get_record().get <age> () << std::endl;
```

Something similar (type tagging) is implemented in boost::property_map, but I ca'nt get my head around how to implement it in a tuple with arbitary number of elements

PS
Please do **not** suggest defining an enum with tuple element indices.

**UPD**
OK, here is a motivation. In my projects I need to be able to define lots of different tuples 'on-the-fly' and all of them need to have certain common functions and operators. This is not possible to achieve with structs

**UPD2**
Actually my example is probably a bit unrealistic to implement. How about this?

```
tagged_tuple <tag<name, std::string>, tag<age, int>, tag<email, std::string>> get_record (); {/*...*/}
// And then somewhere else

std::cout << "Age: " << get_record().get <age> () << std::endl;
```

Comment: What is your objection to using `enum`?

Comment: It's called a `struct`?

Comment: How do you want it to be different from a class with `name`, `age` and `email` public data members? Do you need it to *also* be accessible with `get<0>`? Convertible to `tuple`? Accessed via a pointer-to-tuple? Or is the only required feature the `get<age>()` syntax rather than `.age`?

Comment: j_random_hacker, I want to be able to define a tuple with tags on the spot as in above example

Comment: Steve Jessop, no I don't need any of that.

Comment: If you don't need any of the stuff Steve suggested, a plain old `struct` is perfect. BTW, put a "@" in front of a username to notify that user of your comment.

Comment: @aleguna: if you don't need any `tuple` functionality then I'd say use `struct {std::string name, int age, std::string email} get_record();`. You *could* name the return type, but in C++11 it's not really necessary since it can be captured with `auto` or `decltype`.

Comment: Do you want the special `tagged_tuple` so you have compatibility with `std::tuple`, so you could pass your `tagged_tuple` where a `std::tuple` is expected? If you don't care about compatibility with `std::tuple` then `struct` is the way to go.

Comment: @Steve Jessop, structs are not an option, please see an update to my question

Comment: You can almost certainly define all the common operations you need using function templates, defined outside of any particular class but within the namespace containing these classes.  These can be specialised for each class if necessary.

Comment: What would `get_record().get<std::string>()` return? Or you only want tuples where all members are of different types?

Comment: The how about e.g. `std::map` and [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/any.html)? Put it in a common class for the common operations (operator overloading or just member functions). It seems to me by your clarification that you want to create objects with different members _runtime_ and then you can't use e.g. `std::tuple` (or similar) as they have their members defined _compile time_.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, and how would you define universal function to dump the context of the struct to the log?

Comment: @aleguna: If you have to name the arguments (and therefore *cannot* iterate over them), then how would *you* be able to do it?

Comment: @aleguna: OK, so the tuple-like property that you need is the ability to use a template parameter pack to recursively capture the type of one element at a time? At least, that's the most obvious way I can think of to log a tuple.

Comment: @Bo Persson, get_record().get<email>() not get_record().get<std::string>(). email is an dummy type used for tagging. Please see boost::property_maps tagging implementation

Comment: @Steve Jessop et al, please see my update

Comment: Fair enough.  I wish C++ would let you iterate over the elements of a `struct` at compile-time using template metaprogramming.  Since `std::pair` and `std::tuple` already allow this, it must be possible to design the language do this for ordinary `struct`s too, and if that were the case then we wouldn't need special `tuple` types in the first place.

Comment: So, in conclusion, exactly what you want is not possible. You should maybe give requirements in order of importance, to get reasonable suggestions. Like, how about a custom map, which stores some sort of variants (to support arbitrary data types), and where constructor takes valid map keys and their allowed types, and accessor methods which check these at runtime.

Comment: @Steve : One _must_ name the return type – §8.3.5/9: "*Types shall not be defined in return or parameter types. ...*"

Comment: @ildjarn: my mistake. Still, you don't actually *have* to name the type, you could `struct { blah } dummyobj; auto get_record() -> decltype(dummyobj);` can't you? Although the only reason I can immediately think of for doing that is to cling stubbornly to my claim ;-)

Comment: @ildjarn: With c++14 auto return type deduction returning anonymous struct is all the more easy:

    auto foo() {
        struct {
            std::string name;
            int age;
        } a{"abc", 10};
        
        return a;
    }
    
    int main() {
        return foo().age;
    }

Comment: fwiw, C++14 tuples support extraction by type, so long as there's only 1 element of that type in the tuple. so you get an 'implicit' tag for each uniquely typed member. good enough for some situations

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I'm not aware of any existing class that does this, but it's fairly easy to throw something together using a `std::tuple` and an indexing typelist:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Ts> struct typelist {
  template<typename T> using prepend = typelist<T, Ts...>;
};

template<typename T, typename... Ts> struct index;
template<typename T, typename... Ts> struct index<T, T, Ts...>:
  std::integral_constant<int, 0> {};
template<typename T, typename U, typename... Ts> struct index<T, U, Ts...>:
  std::integral_constant<int, index<T, Ts...>::value + 1> {};

template<int n, typename... Ts> struct nth_impl;
template<typename T, typename... Ts> struct nth_impl<0, T, Ts...> {
  using type = T; };
template<int n, typename T, typename... Ts> struct nth_impl<n, T, Ts...> {
  using type = typename nth_impl<n - 1, Ts...>::type; };
template<int n, typename... Ts> using nth = typename nth_impl<n, Ts...>::type;

template<int n, int m, typename... Ts> struct extract_impl;
template<int n, int m, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct extract_impl<n, m, T, Ts...>: extract_impl<n, m - 1, Ts...> {};
template<int n, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct extract_impl<n, 0, T, Ts...> { using types = typename
  extract_impl<n, n - 1, Ts...>::types::template prepend<T>; };
template<int n, int m> struct extract_impl<n, m> {
  using types = typelist<>; };
template<int n, int m, typename... Ts> using extract = typename
  extract_impl<n, m, Ts...>::types;

template<typename S, typename T> struct tt_impl;
template<typename... Ss, typename... Ts>
struct tt_impl<typelist<Ss...>, typelist<Ts...>>:
  public std::tuple<Ts...> {
  template<typename... Args> tt_impl(Args &&...args):
    std::tuple<Ts...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
  template<typename S> nth<index<S, Ss...>::value, Ts...> get() {
    return std::get<index<S, Ss...>::value>(*this); }
};
template<typename... Ts> struct tagged_tuple:
  tt_impl<extract<2, 0, Ts...>, extract<2, 1, Ts...>> {
  template<typename... Args> tagged_tuple(Args &&...args):
    tt_impl<extract<2, 0, Ts...>, extract<2, 1, Ts...>>(
      std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};

struct name {};
struct age {};
struct email {};

tagged_tuple<name, std::string, age, int, email, std::string> get_record() {
  return { "Bob", 32, "bob@bob.bob"};
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Age: " << get_record().get<age>() << std::endl;
}
```

You'll probably want to write `const` and rvalue `get` accessors on top of the existing one.

Comment: ecatmur, you kung-fu is good, I need some time to meditate over this :)

Comment: +1 for creativity, but I can't actually see the benefit of creating a bunch of empty tag `struct`s over just using an `enum` and the usual `std::tuple`.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, benefit is that e.g. a email can have different index in different tuples. consider `template <class Tuple> void print_email (const Tuple& t) {std::cout << t.get<email>();}` This is not possible with index

Comment: @Mehrdad Actually, it could be really really easier ^^. But it works ^^

Comment: While above example is fairly easy for anyone who's spent a month or two in Template Metaprogramming-land, it is _not_ for the average pragmatic C++-developer. (This is why we hide abstractions in libraries, kids!)

Comment: I take it "fairly easy" when said by you has about the same meaning as "clearly" when said by mathematicians.

Answer (score 10):

C++ does not have a `struct` type that can be iteratable like a `tuple`; it's either/or.

The closest you can get to that is through Boost.Fusion's [struct adapter](http://www.boost.org/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct.html). This allows you to use a struct as a Fusion sequence. Of course, this also uses a series of macros, and it requires you to list the struct's members explicitly in the order you want to iterate over them. In the header (assuming you want to iterate over the struct in many translation units).

> Actually my example is probably a bit unrealistic to implement. How about this?

You could implement something like that, but those identifiers need to actually be types or variables or something.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Boost.Fusion – it's immediately what came to mind when I read the OP's question.

Answer (score 9):

I have my own implementation to show off, wich can allow you not to declare the attributes on top of the file. A version with declared attributes exists too, but there is no need to define them, declaration is sufficient.

It is pure STL, of course, and do not use the preprocessor.

Example:

```
#include <named_tuples/tuple.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace {
unsigned constexpr operator "" _h(const char* c,size_t) { return named_tuples::const_hash(c); }
template <unsigned Id> using at = named_tuples::attribute_init_int_placeholder<Id>;
using named_tuples::make_tuple;
}

int main() {
  auto test = make_tuple( 
      at<"nom"_h>() = std::string("Roger")
      , at<"age"_h>() = 47
      , at<"taille"_h>() = 1.92
      , at<"liste"_h>() = std::vector<int>({1,2,3})
      );

  std::cout 
    << test.at<"nom"_h>() << "\n"
    << test.at<"age"_h>() << "\n"
    << test.at<"taille"_h>() << "\n"
    << test.at<"liste"_h>().size() << std::endl;

  test.at<"nom"_h>() = "Marcel";
  ++test.get<1>();

  std::cout 
    << test.get<0>() << "\n"
    << test.get<1>() << "\n"
    << test.get<2>() << "\n"
    << test.get<3>().size() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Find the complete source here https://github.com/duckie/named_tuple. Feel free to read, it is quite simple.

Answer (score 2):

The real problems you have to solve here are:

- Are the tags mandatory or optional?
- Are the tags unique? Is it enforced at compile time?
- In which scope does the tag reside? Your example seems to declare the tags inside the declaring scope instead of encapsulated in the type, which might not be optimal.

[ecatmur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13066078/401200) proposed a good solution; but the tags are not encapsulated and the tag declaration is somehow clumsy. C++14 will introduce [tuple addressing by type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++14#Tuple_addressing_via_type), which will simplify his design and guarantee uniqueness of the tags, but not solve their scope.

[Boost Fusion Map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/map.html) can also be used for something similar, but again, declaring the tags is not ideal.

There is a proposal for something similar on the [c++ Standard Proposal forum](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!msg/std-proposals/N-kIXNrkTUk/s5iXjc7jzT8J), which would simplify the syntax by associating a name to the template parameter directly.

[This link](https://bitbucket.org/tlutz/named-variadic-template-proposal) lists different ways of implementing this (including [ecatmur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13066078/401200)'s solution) and presents a different use-case for this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I have "solved" a similar problem in production code. First, I have an ordinary struct (actually a class with various member functions, but it's only the data members which we are interested in here)...

```
class Record
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
    std::string email;
    MYLIB_ENABLE_TUPLE(Record) // macro
};
```

Then just below the struct definition, but outside of any namespace, I have another macro:

```
MYLIB_DECLARE_TUPLE(Record, (o.name, o.age, o.email))
```

The disadvantage with this approach is that the member names must be listed twice, but this is the best I have been able to come up with while still permitting traditional member access syntax within the struct's own member functions. The macro appears very near the definitions of the data members themselves, so it is not too hard to keep them in sync with each other.

In another header file I have a class template:

```
template <class T>
class TupleConverter;
```

The first macro is defined so as to declare this template to be a `friend` of the struct, so it can access its private data members:

```
#define MYLIB_ENABLE_TUPLE(TYPE) friend class TupleConverter<TYPE>;
```

The second macro is defined so as to introduce a specialization of the template:

```
#define MYLIB_DECLARE_TUPLE(TYPE, MEMBERS) \
    template <>                            \
    class TupleConverter<TYPE>             \
    {                                      \
        friend class TYPE;                 \
        static auto toTuple(TYPE& o)       \
            -> decltype(std::tie MEMBERS)  \
        {                                  \
            return std::tie MEMBERS;       \
        }                                  \
    public:                                \
        static auto toTuple(TYPE const& o) \
            -> decltype(std::tie MEMBERS)  \
        {                                  \
            return std::tie MEMBERS;       \
        }                                  \
    };
```

This creates two overloads of the same member function name, `TupleConverter<Record>::toTuple(Record const&)` which is public, and `TupleConverter<Record>::toTuple(Record&)` which is private and accessible only to `Record` itself through friendship. Both return their argument converted to a tuple of references to private data members by way of `std::tie`. The public const overload returns a tuple of references to const, the private non-const overload returns a tuple of references to non-const.

After preprocessor substitution, both `friend` declarations refer to entities defined in the same header file, so there should be no chance of other code abusing the friendship to break encapsulation.

`toTuple` can't be a member function of `Record`, because its return type can't be deduced until the definition of `Record` is complete.

Typical usage looks like this:

```
// lexicographical comparison
bool operator< (Record const& a, Record const& b)
{
    return TupleConverter<Record>::toTuple(a) < TupleConverter<Record>::toTuple(b);
}

// serialization
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, Record const& r)
{
    // requires template<class... Ts> ostream& operator<<(ostream&, tuple<Ts...>) defined elsewhere
    return os << TupleConverter<Record>::toTuple(r);
}
```

There are many ways this could be extended, for example by adding another member function in `TupleConverter` which returns a `std::vector<std::string>` of the names of the data members.

If I'd been allowed to use variadic macros then the solution might have been even better.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it, it's a bit uglier to define the types but it helps prevent errors at compile time because you define the pairs with a `type_pair` class (much like `std::map`). Adding a check to make sure your keys/name are unique at compile time is the next step

Usage:

```
   using user_t = tagged_tuple<type_pair<struct name, std::string>, type_pair<struct age, int>>;
  // it's initialized the same way as a tuple created with the value types of the type pairs (so tuple<string, int> in this case)
  user_t user  { "chris", 21 };
  std::cout << "Name: " << get<name>(user) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Age: " << get<age>(user) << std::endl;
 // you can still access properties via numeric indexes as if the class was defined as tuple<string, int>
  std::cout << "user[0] = " << get<0>(user) << std::endl;
```

I opted against having get be a member function to keep it as similar to std::tuple as possible but you could easily add one to the class. 
[Source code here](https://gist.github.com/ilsken/dd91285d50197d6345f9)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation similar to ecatmur's answer using the brigand metaprogramming library (https://github.com/edouarda/brigand):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <brigand/brigand.hpp>

template<typename Members>
class TaggedTuple{

    template<typename Type>
    struct createMember{
        using type = typename Type::second_type;
    };

    using DataTuple = brigand::transform<Members, createMember<brigand::_1>>;
    using Keys = brigand::keys_as_sequence<Members, brigand::list>;
    brigand::as_tuple<DataTuple> members;

public:

    template<typename TagType>
    auto& get(){
        using index = brigand::index_of<Keys, TagType>;
        return std::get<index::value>(members);
    }
};

int main(){

    struct FloatTag{};
    struct IntTag{};
    struct DoubleTag{};

    TaggedTuple<brigand::map<
            brigand::pair<FloatTag, float>,
            brigand::pair<IntTag, int>,
            brigand::pair<DoubleTag, double>>> tagged;

    tagged.get<DoubleTag>() = 200;
    auto val = tagged.get<DoubleTag>();
    std::cout << val << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here is a small variation on this that uses a type within the Tag struct. I find this makes for a nicer syntax. https://gist.github.com/underdoeg/4c5c616c1ad4cbb718f787eefcab902d

Answer (score 0):

I implemented "c++ named tuple" using boost preprocessor. Please see the Sample usage below. By deriving from tuple, I get comparison, printing, hash, serialization for free (assuming they are defined for tuple).

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_i.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/comma_if.hpp>


#define CM_NAMED_TUPLE_ELEMS_ITR(r, xxx, index, x ) BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(index) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,0,x) 
#define CM_NAMED_TUPLE_ELEMS(seq) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(CM_NAMED_TUPLE_ELEMS_ITR, "dum", seq)
#define CM_NAMED_TUPLE_PROPS_ITR(r, xxx, index, x) \
      BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,0,x) BOOST_PP_CAT(get_, BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,1,x))() const { return get<index>(*this); } \
      void BOOST_PP_CAT(set_, BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,1,x))(const BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2,0,x)& oo) { get<index>(*this) = oo; }
#define CM_NAMED_TUPLE_PROPS(seq) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(CM_NAMED_TUPLE_PROPS_ITR, "dum", seq)
#define cm_named_tuple(Cls, seq) struct Cls : tuple< CM_NAMED_TUPLE_ELEMS(seq)> { \
        typedef tuple<CM_NAMED_TUPLE_ELEMS(seq)> Base;                      \
        Cls() {}                                                            \
        template<class...Args> Cls(Args && ... args) : Base(args...) {}     \
        struct hash : std::hash<CM_NAMED_TUPLE_ELEMS(seq)> {};            \
        CM_NAMED_TUPLE_PROPS(seq)                                           \
        template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive & ar, arg const unsigned int version)() {                                                    \
          ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(*this);                              \
        }                                                                   \
      }

//
// Example:
//
// class Sample {
//   public:
//   void do_tata() {
//     for (auto& dd : bar2_) {
//       cout << dd.get_from() << " " << dd.get_to() << dd.get_tata() << "\n";
//       dd.set_tata(dd.get_tata() * 5);
//     }
//     cout << bar1_ << bar2_ << "\n";
//   }
//
//   cm_named_tuple(Foo, ((int, from))((int, to))((double, tata)));  // Foo == tuple<int,int,double> with named get/set functions
//
//   unordered_set<Foo, Foo::hash> bar1_;
//   vector<Foo> bar2_;  
// };
```

Please note that code sample above assumes you have defined "generic" ostream printing functions for vector/tuple/unordered_set.