# Difference between usage of type size_t and int when used as template type?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am still at basic understanding of meta-programming.

I am struggling to understand the difference, if any, of using the int type or the size_t type when using this type as a template type.

I understand the difference between both in standard c++ programming as explained here [What's the difference between size_t and int in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502856/whats-the-difference-between-size-t-and-int-in-c/502943)

Then when reading questions related to some template tricks, it seems that people tends to use them undifferently. 
For example on this one [How can I get the index of a type in a variadic class template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736242/how-can-i-get-the-index-of-a-type-in-a-variadic-class-template) 
Barry is using std::integral_constant  instantiated with size_t type

In this question: [C++11 Tagged Tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065166/c11-tagged-tuple)
ecatmur provides an answer where its index helpers use int type instance of std::integral.

Modify one with the other seems to have no impact for what I have tested. Those template specialization being recursive, I presume anyway that in practice compiler would collapse if the Index N was too big.

Is choosing int or size_t in this specific context only a question of coding style ?

Comment: You might have issue if you mix them.

Comment: You mean besides the obvious that `int` is a signed integer and `size_t` is an unsigned integer? Or the semantic meaning for the readers of the code seeing e.g. `size_t` and knowing a *size* is expected?

Comment: @Some programmer dude : yes, as I understand it, using int might be more driven by the convention (if such convention exists), that int is a "good enough" type for defining indexes (or at least  broadly used) and that the size_t is programmatically better because it reduces risk of wrong usage. But in this view, unsigned short or unsigned char would be even better as compile time recursive algorithms must in practise be called with small N values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::size_t` is an unsigned type that is at least as large as an `unsigned int`.

`int` is a signed type, whose upper bound is less than that of an `unsigned int`.

There are going to be values which cannot be represented by `int` that `size_t` can represent.

Passing `-1` as an `int` results in a negative value.  Passing `-1` as a `size_t` results in a large positive value.

Overflow on `int` is undefined behavior; undefined behavior at compile time makes expressions non-`constexpr` in some contexts.

Overflow on `size_t` is defined behavior, it is mathematics modulo `2^n` for some (unspecified) `n`.

Many containers in C++ use `size_t` for their indexing, and `tuple` uses it for the index of its `get`.

There are disadvantages to unsigned values, in that they behave strangely (unlike "real integers") "near zero", while `int` behaves strangely far from zero, and being far from zero is a rarer case than being near zero.

`size_t` cannot be negative, which is seemingly makes sense to use to represent values that cannot be negative, but the wrap-around behavior can sometimes cause big problems.  I find this happens less so with compile-time code however.

You could use `ptrdiff_t`, which is basically the signed equivalent of `size_t`, as another choice.

There are consequences to both choices.  Which of these consequences you want to deal with is up to you.  Which is better, a matter of opinion.