# Is there a way to get function parameter names at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have a template that goes approximately like this:

```
template<class out, class... inTypes>
string do_thing(std::function<out(inTypes)> inFunc)
{
Do stuff
}
```

I want to do approximately the following, in sloppy syntax, at compile time:

Do stuff:

```
for (int i =0; i < inTypes.length();++i)
{
obj_that_acts_like_vector.push_back( inFunc.params[i].name_of_paramrter_as_string)
}
```

So if I had a function that took in int myInt, and bool myBool, do stuff would compile to

```
obj_that_acts_like_vector.push_back("myInt"); obj_that_acts_like_vector.push_back("myBool");
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Not inside the language; at least till there's static reflection. People often use macros for this kind of thing.

Comment: Ah well I has suspected that, but I had hoped there was some magic that made it possible.

Comment: you might see the answer of this question tagged tuple which goes in the direction you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065166/c11-tagged-tuple